# ExpressJS Handle multiple get route with the same endpoint

Tags: node.js, rest, express, routes, acl

I build an application API with expressJS. In this application there is a public part and an private part.

Both part need to display a list of user. But only the private part can display the full list.

I use [express-authorize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-authorization) middlewar to handle autorization. So i have defined two authorization :

> 'public:users:list'

and

> 'private:users:list'

In express i have tried to write routes like this :

```
router.route('/users')
    .get([passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), authorization.authorizer.isPermitted('private:users:list')], (req, res) => {
        getUserList(req, res);
    })
    .get([passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), authorization.authorizer.isPermitted('public:users:list')], (req, res) => {
        req.query.filter.roles.name = 'user'
        getUserList(req, res);
    });
```

But this does not work. Request fail as unauthorized on the first get and never goes to the second. Is there a mean to make this works? Or any others techniques. If possible avoid to create another endpoint like (router.route('usersPublic').

Thx

**EDIT:**

I have override the onDenied function like this and make the change in the route.

```
var authorizer = new authorizer.Authorizer(authorizer.options);
authorizer.options.onDenied = function (req, res, next) { next('route') };


authorizer.options.withSubject = function (req, res, done) {}
```

That seems to work. But if no route are valid. i get a 404 error instead of 403. Any suggestion?

**EDIT2:**

onDenied should not be set at global but inside the route itself like this

```
   router.route('/users')..get([passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), authorization.authorizer.onDenied((req, res, next) => next('route')).isPermitted('private:users:list')], (req, res) => {
            getUserList(req, res);
        });

   router.route('/users')..get([passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), authorization.authorizer.isPermitted('public:users:list')], (req, res) => {
        req.query.filter.roles.name = 'user'
        getUserList(req, res);
    });
```

Comment: why cant you just have two conditions in a same block?

Comment: I can. But want to handle all authorisation with the middleware if possible

Comment: as per my understanding its not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `express-authorize`, so the following is pieced together from its source and may not work.

First, you need to change how authentication mismatches are handled. The default is to redirect to `/login`, but you need to change that so the request gets passed to the next route chain:

```
let myAuthorizer = authorization.authorizer.onDenied((req, res, next) => next('route'));
```

Then you need to set up two separate routes for `/users`:

```
router.route('/users').get([passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), myAuthorizer.isPermitted('private:users:list') ], (req, res) => {
  getUserList(req, res);
})

router.route('/users').get([passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), authorization.authorizer.isPermitted('public:users:list')], (req, res) => {
  req.query.filter.roles.name = 'user'
  getUserList(req, res);
});
```

The `next('route')` is explained [here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-handlers), but it basically means that instead of passing the request to the next handler in the current chain, it's passed to the next full route chain (which in this case is the second `router.route('/users')` if private access is denied).

Comment: @Scandinave thinking about it, you probably shouldn't use the `onDenied` for the second route, and let the default handler take care of authorization failures (redirecting to `/login`). I'll edit my answer, see if that solves your 404 (although from what I understand in your question, you're setting the global `onDenied`, which you probably shouldn't).